# What should i do to assign values from input stream to 3D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I got several inputs data with `ifstream`, it looks like:

```
ifstream Input1, Input2, Input3;
Input1.open(arg[1]);
Input2.open(arg[2]);
Input3.open(arg[3]);
```

And I have a 3D array which I plan to use for these three streams, Depth is three (each layer stores one input). The dynamic 3D array is created `array[Depth][Rows][Colons]`. I plan to do something similar to the scenario 'one input in 2D array': operator `>>` in the 2D for loops, now code block looks like:

```
for(int h = 0; h < Depth; h ++){
  for(int i = 0; i < Rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < Colons; j++){
      //assign the values
      array[h][i][j] = vector[i]; //what i did in my assignment, vector is the merged three vectors for three input stream
    }
  }
}
```

I have no clue now, what shall i do/think now?

**Edit**:
It's a programming homework that I've already submitted. It requires me to use dynamic 3D array to store the stream data and do the computation.

What I did is, using three separate vectors to store three streams, then using the `insert`method to merge three vectors. Then `array[h][i][j] = vector[i]` in the loop. I'm wondering if there are some more effective and right ways to do this by directly using operator `>>` .

Comment: I don't understand how three streams are supposed to fill a 3D array.  For example, if your array is 2x4x2, you have 16 total scalar elements.  And these come from three input streams how?  (Also, `"arg[1]"` is an extremely unusual filename.  It really contains bracket characters in the filesystem?)

Comment: @aschepler my fault, fixed.

Comment: Why would you need stream operator for that as well as three separate streams? Isn't it easier to pass the path to the three files to some array class method and handle it internally by opening the files one by one?

Comment: @KjMag see my edit.

Comment: Are `Rows` and `Colons` known at compile time? Does each file contain only the data needed to fill a 2D array? Can you give us a numeric example of the original data and the required outcome? What exactly do you mean with *dynamic* 3D array, how have you declared it?